# testcafe/testcafe- base alpine image fails to run msnodesqlv8 in docker

Tags: docker, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Hello I am dockerizing my testcafe project and my package.json has a dependency to install msnodesqlv8. Looks like my docker file is failing , what am i doing wrong here?

```
  deasync@0.1.21 install /app/node_modules/deasync
 > node ./build.js

 `linux-x64-node-14` exists; testing
  Binary is fine; exiting

  > msnodesqlv8@2.0.12 install /app/node_modules/msnodesqlv8
  > prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild

  prebuild-install WARN install Error loading shared library libmsodbcsql-17.so: N                                                                                                                                  
  o such file or directory (needed by /app/node_modules/msnodesqlv8/build/Release/                                                                                                                                  
  sqlserverv8.node)
  gyp ERR! build error
  gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
  gyp ERR! stack     at getNotFoundError (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/w                                                                                                                                  
  hich/which.js:13:12)
  gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:6                                                                                                                                  
   8:19)
  gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:8                                                                                                                                  
  0:29)
  gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:89:1                                                                                                                                  
  6
  gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
  gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
  gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:183:21)
  gyp ERR! System Linux 4.19.76-linuxkit
  gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gy                                                                                                                                  
  p/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
  gyp ERR! cwd /app/node_modules/msnodesqlv8
  gyp ERR! node -v v14.16.0
  gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
 gyp ERR! not ok
  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
  npm ERR! errno 1
  npm ERR! msnodesqlv8@2.0.12 install: `prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild`
  npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

My Dockerfile is as below, what am i doing wrong here? why is docker failing?

```
FROM testcafe/testcafe
USER root
WORKDIR /app
COPY .npmrc .npmrc
COPY package*.json ./
RUN apk add --no-cache python3 py3-pip
RUN npm cache verify && npm install
COPY . .
USER user
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that the 'make' utility is missing.
Try to install it with the following command:

`RUN apk install build-essential`